# count the files inside subfolders and sort the display

Tags: find, sort

so I have the following script

```
find "my-path-here"  -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -type d -exec sh -c 'echo "{} : $(find "{}" -type f | wc -l | sort)" file\(s\)' \;
```

and it counts the files (recursively) on the all the folders (depth=1)

The screenshot below was run against /usr and as can be seen, the folders are not sorted alphabetically.

Any ideas on how to change the command so it comes out alphabetically sorted?

Thanks

[image]

Comment: Possibly a duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9157138/recursively-counting-files-in-a-linux-directory

Comment: Add `| sort` after your command and you'll get sorted result by first field

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to do it, assuming GNU `find` and assuming your filenames don't have embedded newlines:

```
find /some/dir -type f -printf '%P\n' | grep / | cut -d/ -f1 | sort | uniq -c
```

Sample output:

```
 5322 X11R6
  316 bin
   89 lib
 2165 libdata
   50 libexec
19220 local
   10 mdec
  206 sbin
 8970 share
```

You can use `awk` or `sed` to format this if you need to.